# Give a metric d on R such that Q is open in the metric space topology on (R,d)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Give a metric d on R such that Q is open in the metric space topology on (R,d).

I'm thinking about $d(m,n)=|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}|$ and I'm  not sure if this metric makes Q open in R. If not, can anyone give me an example which satisfies the above condition?

Comment: Might be worth noting that your metric isn't well defined on Q - what's $d(0, 1)$?

Answer (score 0):

Take discrete metric: $d (x,y)=1$ for $x \neq y $ and $d (x,x)=0$. Any set is open in this metric.